# CSS text-overflow: ellipsis not working in when using CSS grid

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid, ellipsis

I am unable to get ellipsis working in CSS grid

I've tried the following:

Parent Grid Container:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Child Grid Item:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Code Sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/eternalshenron/xvm82jpd/20/

```css
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  nb-card-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  
  .h1-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  
  .h2-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: #373737;
  }
  
  .h3-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #545454;
  }
  
  .h4-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #373737;
  }
  
  .card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "location misc-details";
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
  }
  
  .location {
    grid-area: location;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "seperator from-to";
  }
  
  .from-to {
    grid-area: from-to;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:  "location-1" 
                          "location-2"
  }
  
  .location-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-1;
    align-self: top;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .location-2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-2;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .loc {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  .seperator {
    grid-area: seperator;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas:  "dot-start" 
                          "line" 
                          "dot-end";
  }
  
  .line {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
    justify-self: center;
  }
      
  .dot-start {
    grid-area: dot-start;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
    
  .dot-end {
    grid-area: dot-end;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.65em;
  }
  
  .misc-details {
    grid-area: misc-details;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: right;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content 1fr;    
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-type"
                          "seperator-2"
                          "other-details";
  }
  
  .vehicle-load {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: max-content;
    grid-template-areas:   "vehicle"
                          "load-size";
  }
  
  .vehicle {
    grid-area: vehicle;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: center;
    grid-template-columns: max-content min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-icon vehicle-type";
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  
  .vehicle-icon {
    grid-area: vehicle-icon;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
  
  .vehicle-type {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  
  .load-size {
    grid-area: load-size;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }
  
  img {
      max-width: 4em;
  }
  
  .other-details {
    grid-area: other-details;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .gray-line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #545454;
  }
  
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  nb-card-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }

  .h1-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 115%;
    color: #373737;
  }

  .h2-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: #373737;
  }

  .h3-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #545454;
  }

  .h4-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #373737;
  }

  .card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "location misc-details";
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
  }

  .location {
    grid-area: location;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "seperator from-to";
  }

  .from-to {
    grid-area: from-to;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:  "location-1" 
                          "location-2";
  }

  .location-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-1;
    align-self: top;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .location-2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-2;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .loc {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .seperator {
    grid-area: seperator;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas:  "dot-start" 
                          "line" 
                          "dot-end";
  }

  .line {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
    justify-self: center;
  }
      
  .dot-start {
    grid-area: dot-start;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
    
  .dot-end {
    grid-area: dot-end;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.65em;
  }

  .misc-details {
    grid-area: misc-details;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: right;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content 1fr;    
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-type"
                          "seperator-2"
                          "other-details";
  }

  .vehicle-load {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: max-content;
    grid-template-areas:   "vehicle"
                          "load-size";
  }

  .vehicle {
    grid-area: vehicle;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: center;
    grid-template-columns: max-content min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-icon vehicle-type";
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }

  .vehicle-icon {
    grid-area: vehicle-icon;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }

  .vehicle-type {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .load-size {
    grid-area: load-size;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }

  img {
      max-width: 8em;
  }

  .other-details {
    grid-area: other-details;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .gray-line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #545454;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  nb-card-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }

  .h1-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 115%;
    color: #373737;
  }

  .h2-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: #373737;
  }

  .h3-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #545454;
  }

  .h4-card {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #373737;
  }

  .card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "location location location location vehicle-type vehicle-type vehicle-type vehicle-type other-details other-details";
  }

  .location {
    grid-area: location;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr max-content;
    grid-template-areas: "location-1 seperator location-2";
  }

  .location-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-1;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .location-2 {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    grid-area: location-2;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: right;
    text-align: right;
  }

  .loc {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .seperator {
    grid-area: seperator;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "dot-start line dot-end";
  }

  hr.line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid black;
  }
      
  .dot-start {
    grid-area: dot-start;  
    justify-self: center;
  }
    
  .dot-end {
    grid-area: dot-end;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    justify-self: center;
  }

  .vehicle-load {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: max-content;
    grid-template-areas:   "vehicle"
                          "load-size";
  }

  .vehicle {
    grid-area: vehicle;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-icon vehicle-type";
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }

  .vehicle-icon {
    grid-area: vehicle-icon;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }

  .vehicle-type {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }

  .load-size {
    grid-area: load-size;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }

  img {
      max-width: 8em;
  }

  .other-details {
    grid-area: other-details;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .gray-line {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #545454;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="location">
    <div class="from-to overflow">
      <div class="location-1 ellipsis">
        <div class="loc ellipsis">
          <span class="h1-card">Thiruvananthapuram City</span><br>
          <span class="h3-card">Thiruvananthapuram
            <br>Kerala</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="location-2">
        <p class="loc ellipsis">
          <span class="h1-card">Venkatanarasimharajuvaripeta</span><br>
          <span class="h3-card">Chitoor
            <br>Andhra Pradesh</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seperator">
      <svg height="1.2em" width="1.2em" class="dot-start">
        <circle cx="0.6em" cy="0.74em" r="0.4em" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.06em" fill="lightgreen" />
      </svg>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <svg height="1.2em" width="1.2em" class="dot-end">
        <circle cx="0.6em" cy="0.5em" r="0.4em" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.12em" fill="white" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="misc-details">
    <div class="vehicle-load">
      <div class="vehicle">
        <div class="vehicle-icon"> ICON ICON ICON </div>
        <div class="vehicle-type"><span class="h2-card">Trailer</span><br>
          <span class="h4-card">Load</span></div>
      </div>              
      <div class="h2-card load-size">40' x 10' x 8' | 20 Tons</div>
    </div>
    <hr class="gray-line" />
    <div class="other-details">
      <div class="load-type h2-card">ODC Cargo</div>
      <hr class="gray-line" />
      <div class="loading-date h2-card">Tue | 22 Sep</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add all code to the question and not just have a link to jsfiddle otherwise your question is off topic

Comment: You need to add a `width` and a `display` to it; see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59ykmjo1/)

Comment: Try to include all relevant information in the question, and to remove all irrelevant information. This makes the question specific and to the point, which makes it easier for us to answer your question. More information here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Pete and mikabytes. Thanks for pointing out the problems. Highly appreciate. I'll ensure to avoid them going ahead.

Comment: MattHamer5. Thanks for the solution. The given solution is not working when we resize the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `max-width:100%` to avoid the overflow and `min-width:0` to allow the shrink of the items:

```
.ellipsis {
    ...
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

Make sure to add the class to location-1 and location-2

Full code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  nb-card-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  .h1-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .h2-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 550;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .h3-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #545454;
  }
  .h4-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "location misc-details";
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
  }
  .location {
    grid-area: location;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "seperator from-to";
  }
  .from-to {
    grid-area: from-to;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "location-1" "location-2"
  }
  .location-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-1;
    align-self: top;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .location-2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-2;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .loc {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .seperator {
    grid-area: seperator;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "dot-start" "line" "dot-end";
  }
  .line {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
    justify-self: center;
  }
  .dot-start {
    grid-area: dot-start;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .dot-end {
    grid-area: dot-end;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.65em;
  }
  .misc-details {
    grid-area: misc-details;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: right;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-type" "seperator-2" "other-details";
  }
  .vehicle-load {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: max-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle" "load-size";
  }
  .vehicle {
    grid-area: vehicle;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: center;
    grid-template-columns: max-content min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-icon vehicle-type";
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  .vehicle-icon {
    grid-area: vehicle-icon;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
  .vehicle-type {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .load-size {
    grid-area: load-size;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 4em;
  }
  .other-details {
    grid-area: other-details;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .gray-line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #545454;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  nb-card-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  .h1-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 115%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .h2-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 105%;
    font-weight: 550;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .h3-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #545454;
  }
  .h4-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "location misc-details";
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
  }
  .location {
    grid-area: location;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "seperator from-to";
  }
  .from-to {
    grid-area: from-to;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "location-1" "location-2";
  }
  .location-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-1;
    align-self: top;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .location-2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-2;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .loc {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .seperator {
    grid-area: seperator;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "dot-start" "line" "dot-end";
  }
  .line {
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px solid black;
    justify-self: center;
  }
  .dot-start {
    grid-area: dot-start;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .dot-end {
    grid-area: dot-end;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.65em;
  }
  .misc-details {
    grid-area: misc-details;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: right;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr max-content 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-type" "seperator-2" "other-details";
  }
  .vehicle-load {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: max-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle" "load-size";
  }
  .vehicle {
    grid-area: vehicle;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: center;
    grid-template-columns: max-content min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-icon vehicle-type";
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  .vehicle-icon {
    grid-area: vehicle-icon;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
  .vehicle-type {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .load-size {
    grid-area: load-size;
    justify-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 8em;
  }
  .other-details {
    grid-area: other-details;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .gray-line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #545454;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  nb-card-header {
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  .h1-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 550;
    font-size: 115%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .h2-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 105%;
    font-weight: 550;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .h3-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #545454;
  }
  .h4-card {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #373737;
  }
  .card-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "location location location location vehicle-type vehicle-type vehicle-type vehicle-type other-details other-details";
  }
  .location {
    grid-area: location;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr max-content;
    grid-template-areas: "location-1 seperator location-2";
  }
  .location-1 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    grid-area: location-1;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: left;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .location-2 {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    grid-area: location-2;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: right;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .loc {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .seperator {
    grid-area: seperator;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "dot-start line dot-end";
  }
  hr.line {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid black;
  }
  .dot-start {
    grid-area: dot-start;
    justify-self: center;
  }
  .dot-end {
    grid-area: dot-end;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    justify-self: center;
  }
  .vehicle-load {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-self: center;
    justify-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: max-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle" "load-size";
  }
  .vehicle {
    grid-area: vehicle;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content min-content;
    grid-template-areas: "vehicle-icon vehicle-type";
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  .vehicle-icon {
    grid-area: vehicle-icon;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
  .vehicle-type {
    grid-area: vehicle-type;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .load-size {
    grid-area: load-size;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 8em;
  }
  .other-details {
    grid-area: other-details;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .gray-line {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px solid #545454;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="location">
    <div class="from-to overflow">
      <div class="location-1 ellipsis">
        <div class="loc ellipsis">
          <span class="h1-card">Thiruvananthapuram City</span><br>
          <span class="h3-card">Thiruvananthapuram
            <br>Kerala</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="location-2 ellipsis">
        <p class="loc ellipsis">
          <span class="h1-card">Venkatanarasimharajuvaripeta</span><br>
          <span class="h3-card">Chitoor
            <br>Andhra Pradesh</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="seperator">
      <svg height="1.2em" width="1.2em" class="dot-start">
        <circle cx="0.6em" cy="0.74em" r="0.4em" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.06em" fill="lightgreen" />
      </svg>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <svg height="1.2em" width="1.2em" class="dot-end">
        <circle cx="0.6em" cy="0.5em" r="0.4em" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.12em" fill="white" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="misc-details">
    <div class="vehicle-load">
      <div class="vehicle">
        <div class="vehicle-icon"> ICON ICON ICON </div>
        <div class="vehicle-type"><span class="h2-card">Trailer</span><br>
          <span class="h4-card">Load</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="h2-card load-size">40' x 10' x 8' | 20 Tons</div>
    </div>
    <hr class="gray-line" />
    <div class="other-details">
      <div class="load-type h2-card">ODC Cargo</div>
      <hr class="gray-line" />
      <div class="loading-date h2-card">Tue | 22 Sep</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The solution works perfectly. I had a doubt:
Q: If I remove the min-width: 0 property, the solution still works. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @eternalshenron when using grid a default configuration is `min-width:auto` which doesn't allow an element to shrink past its content, by setting `min-width:0` you disable this. You may not need it but since you are creating a generic rule better have it and it will work when needed. max-width:100% may also be useless in cases by the way.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer 10 times, there are many other answers to this problem around the web, but this is the only one I found with the max-width setting.